# How to have the same background image for body and png img?

Tags: css

I'm trying to display some images without background on a body with a background image, but it looks like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bw5lL.png)

I would like to see only the cat and the space background. Can you help me pls?

I also tried to have a dark background color for the body and it doesn't work.

Comment: share your code

Comment: The cat image clearly has a checkered background. You should remove the background from the image.

Comment: Is  your **cat image** a **PNG** and has an **Empty background** ?

Comment: Convert the image format from png to jpg to have white background around the cat image..

Comment: you need to used the png image and their background will be transform  for the cat image

Comment: I noticed that my image was a jpg instead a png xd
I tried with a png and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

the main background will be jpg image and cat image will be transferred background like this attachment image

[image]

[image]

[image]